# How to know if the child has been tapped even if it was on a button?

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I would like to create a `Widget` which can detect when the user tapped on it. To do so I used a `GestureGetector` with an `onTap` function to detect it.
However, if the child contains a button, the `onTap` callback is never called.

Here is an example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(
        child: UnkownWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    @required this.child,
  });

  final Widget child;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {
          print('tapped');
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: child,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UnkownWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 150.0,
      height: 150.0,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: TextButton(
        child: Text('Button'),
        onPressed: () {
          print('Button pressed');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

When I click on the blue `Container`, I see `tapped` in the console but when I click on the red one, I only see `Button pressed` (and no `tapped`) but I would like both callbacks to be triggered.

I tried with `HitTestBehavior.deferToChild` / `HitTestBehavior.translucent` / `HitTestBehavior.opaque` but it didn't change anything.

---

I also should specify I don't have any control over the `UnkownWidget` as it can be anything, and I still want `UnkownWidget` to behave properly (still get triggered by a tap on its buttons).

---

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do something like that in Flutter.

But fortunately I though of a work-around for this. So what you can do is call the onTap function of blue container inside the onTap function of red container. This will simulate an effect that both the containers are tapped when actually only red one was tapped :

Follow this question to get solution code for doing the same :

[How do I programmatically simulate onTap on a button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63589071/how-do-i-programmatically-simulate-ontap-on-a-button-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks, but as I described, I don't have control over the `UnkownWidget` which can be anything, so I cannot modify it to call the `onTap` function of the blue `Container` from the red one...