# How to call the onTap method of a built GestureDetector?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I am using the flutter package AnimatedTextKit which displays some animated text.
(https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit)

An AnimatedTextKit is a StatefulWidget and builds a GestureDetector :

```
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final completeText = _currentAnimatedText.completeText(context);
return GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onTap: _onTap,
  child: _isCurrentlyPausing || !_controller.isAnimating
      ? completeText
      : AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: _currentAnimatedText.animatedBuilder,
          child: completeText,
        ),
);
}
```

I wrap the AnimatedTextKit into a Card, and also show a yellow triangle at the bottom of the Card when the text is fully displayed :

[Card containing an AnimatedTextKit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BWpw.png)

When I tap on the text : it's fine since the AnimatedTextKit GestureDetector detects the tap. But when I tap on the yellow triangle just below, because I tap outside the AnimatedTextKit widget, the tap is not detected, which is normal.

Is there a clean way to make a tap made anywhere on the Card be interpreted as a tap on the AnimatedTextKit ?

I have looked at these answers : [How to pass Taps to widgets below the top widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929582/how-to-pass-taps-to-widgets-below-the-top-widget) and [How do I programmatically simulate onTap on a button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63589071/how-do-i-programmatically-simulate-ontap-on-a-button-in-flutter) but I feel like I'm not able to apply the proposed solutions since I cannot modify the AnimatedTextKit library code.

Comment: put your triangle widget in gesturedetector